# Lua c lib Windows: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: c, windows, lua

I have Lua 5.3.5 64-bit installed on my machine. I am compiling a 64-bit `dll` to test the c api process. Here is my file, `driver.c`:

```c
#define LUA_LIB

#include "lua/lua.h"
#include "lua/lualib.h"
#include "lua/lauxlib.h"

static int returnone(lua_State *L) {
    return 1;
}

static const luaL_Reg lualib[] = {
    {"returnone", returnone},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_lualib(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, lualib);
    return 1;
}
```

This outputs to `lualib.dll`

I created a script, `test.lua` in the same directory as `lualib.dll`.

```lua
require("lualib");
```

I get this:

```
$ lua.exe test.lua
C:\Program Files\Lua\lua.exe: error loading module 'lualib' from file '.\lualib.dll':
        The specified procedure could not be found.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        test.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Then I try

```
print(package.loadlib("lualib", "luaopen_lualib"));
```

And I get

```
$ lua.exe test.lua
nil     The specified procedure could not be found.
        init
```

I am stumped. Where's my library?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building to Lua module to windows DLL you need to use `__declspec(dllexport)` e.g. this should be enough for the most simple cases:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_lualib(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, lualib);
    return 1;
}
```

Please refer to [Building Modules](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingModules) on lua-users.

As for a more verbose example I would suggest luasocket: [source](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/luasocket.c#L96-L104), [header](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/luasocket.h#L16-L34).